# Symfony DQL - transform the array query result

Tags: sql, symfony, dql

I'm trying to transform the array of my query result.

First I did this query:

```
public function findAllTraduction()
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->select('c.key, c.content, c.id, f.locale')
        ->leftJoin('c.TraductionFile', 'f')
        ->groupBy('c.key')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getArrayResult();
}
```

The result is like that:

```
array 
  0 => 
    array 
      'key' => string 'FORMAT1' 
      'content' => string 'login'
      'id' => int 507
      'locale' => string 'en'
  1 => 
    array 
      'key' => string 'FORMAT1'
      'content' => string 'connecter' 
      'id' => int 508
      'locale' => string 'fr' 
  2 => 
    array
      'key' => string 'FORMAT2' 
      'content' => string 'password' 
      'id' => int 503
      'locale' => string 'en' 
  3 => 
    array 
      'key' => string 'FORMAT2' 
      'content' => string 'mot de passe'
      'id' => int 504
      'locale' => string 'fr'
```

What I would like to have is an array like that:

```
array
  'FORMAT1' => 
    array
      'en' =>
        array
          'content' => string 'login'
          'id' => int 507
      'fr' =>
        array
          'content' => string 'connecter'
          'id' => int 508
  'FORMAT2' => 
    array
      'en' =>
        array
          'content' => string 'password'
          'id' => int 503
      'fr' =>
        array
          'content' => string 'mot de passe'
          'id' => int 504
```

In fact, for each same `'key'` (here `'FORMAT1'` and `'FORMAT2'`, regroup by `'locale'` (`EN` and `FR`)

Is it possible to do that in the query ?

I tried with GROUPBY and DISTINCT but nothing happened...

If not possible in query, may be redraw an array with loop....

thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution with foreach for redraw the array ...

```
$catalogue = [];

        foreach ($catalogues_array as $index => $val) {
            $key = $val['key'];
            $locale = $val['locale'];
            unset($catalogues_array[$index]['key']);
            unset($catalogues_array[$index]['locale']);
            $catalogue[$key][$locale] = $catalogues_array[$index];
        }
        return $catalogue;
```

the result :

```
array (size=421)
  'base_template.page_title' => 
    array (size=2)
      'en' => 
        array (size=6)
          'content' => string 'Audio Video Caption - Subtitling & Transcription of media.' (length=58)
          'description' => null
          'traductionControle' => boolean false
          'id' => int 1
          'domain' => string 'messages' (length=8)
          'bundleName' => string 'app' (length=3)
      'fr' => 
        array (size=6)
          'content' => string 'Audio Video Caption - Sous-Titrage & Transcription de médias.' (length=62)
          'description' => null
          'traductionControle' => boolean false
          'id' => int 9
          'domain' => string 'messages' (length=8)
          'bundleName' => string 'app' (length=3)
  'base_template.meta.keywords' => 
    array (size=2)
      'en' => 
        array (size=6)
          'content' => string 'closed captioning, subtitle, speech recognition, transcription, traduction, video, audio' (length=88)
          'description' => null
          'traductionControle' => boolean false
          'id' => int 2
          'domain' => string 'messages' (length=8)
          'bundleName' => string 'app' (length=3)
      'fr' => 
        array (size=6)
          'content' => string 'sous-titre, reconnaissance vocale, transcription, traduction, video, audio' (length=74)
          'description' => null
          'traductionControle' => boolean false
          'id' => int 10
          'domain' => string 'messages' (length=8)
          'bundleName' => string 'app' (length=3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Doctrine provides a way to specify indexBy when creating the QueryBuilder in order to index the resulting array not in a sequential way but by a specific key :

```
createQueryBuilder($alias, $indexBy = null)
```

So you may want to try something like `createQueryBuilder('c', 'c.key')` to use c keys as array indexes